# Drawing a jack out of a deck with $n$ cards, what is the expected value?

Tags: probability-theory

> Assume you have a deck with $n$ different and mixed cards (fair situation), with one of those cards being a jack. After each draw, you lay the card aside. Let $X$ be the number of cards that you need in order to draw that jack. Then what is the expected value of $X$?

I know that my solution is not correct, but I wonder where I am mistaken:

As $X$ counts the cards we need in order to draw the jack, it might be useful to write

$$X = X_1 + \ ... \ + X_n,$$

with $X_k$ being the random variable representing the $k$-th draw. Specifically, I define

$$X_k =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if the k-th draw is a jack,} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

$X_k$ is bernoulli-distributed, with $(P(X_k) = 1) = {1 \over {n-(k-1)}} $(because with each draw that isn't the jack, one card of the deck is gone).

Using the linearity of the expected value, I receive:

$$E(X) = E(X_1) + \ ... \ + E(X_n) = 1/n + 1/(n-1) + \ ... \ + 1.$$

This doesn't make sense though. Say, I choose $n = 100$, then I'd get an expected value of $5$, which seems way too low.

Comment: The Jack is equally likely to be in any of the $n$ positions.

Comment: Your $X$ equals $1$ and your $X_i$ have equal distribution with $\frac1{n}$ as expectation.

Comment: Thanks! Why are the $X_i$ distributed equally though? It should make a difference whether I draw a card the first or the $100$th time, since with every drawn card that is not a Jack, it becomes more likely that the next card is indeed a Jack, right?

Comment: Remember: I lay the drawn card aside. I don' t put it back in the deck.

Comment: Can you give me one good reason why it is less probable for the jack to be located at first spot than e.g. at last spot?

Comment: The probability does not grow but the *conditional* probability grows. The condition is that the jack has not been encountered in former draws.

Answer (score 1):

The $X$ defined here satisfies  $X=1$ and so does its expectation. It has no proper use here.

Secondly: $P(X_k=1)\neq P(X_k=1\mid X_1=0,\dots,X_{k-1}=0)$

Hint for solution: $X$ and $n+1-X$ have equal distribution hence equal expectation.

Comment: You're right, this question has to something to do with the conditional probability, I didn't think about that. I'll try it again, thanks!

Comment: Actually the original question that was posed had nothing to do with conditional probability.  You just choosed the wrong strategy to solve it and within that strategy you also made the mistake to involve conditional probabilities.